# A second order non-linear ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

While doing some mechanics calculations, I happened to produce the following system of equations $$-my'' -mg\sin a(x) + 2my = 0$$ $$-mgy\cos a(x)-mra''(x)=0,$$
Or more simply:
$$y'' +g\sin a(x) - 2y = 0$$ $$gy\cos a(x)+ra''(x)=0,$$

where $r,m,g$ are constants. Here $y$ and $a$ are both functions of the independent variable $x$. Is it possible to solve this system for the functions $y$ and $a(x)$? Since these equations are not linear, I don't know how I should approach this problem.

Comment: You can solve for $y(a)$ from your first Eqn., then your second equation would be something similar to a pendulum but the cosine term becomes more complicated. The solution for the regular old pendulum is a hypergeometric function, so unless $y(a)$ makes that cosine term nicer you’re looking at something more complicated or as complicated as a hypergeometric.

Comment: It's a four order non linear differential equation in $a(x)$ So complicated to solve. @Eli

Comment: @Aryadeva you are correct

Comment: $\frac 12 y'^2+g y\sin a-y^2+\frac 12r a'^2=C$

Comment: Take a derivative of the first Eqn., substitute $g\cos(a)$ into your second, then integrate and you'll get \begin{align} \frac{r}{2}a'^2+y^2-yy''+\frac{1}{2}y'^2=c.\end{align}
Then you can solve for $a$ using your first equation, and substitute it into this one to get an ODE of just $y$, \begin{align}
r\frac{(2y'-y''')^2}{g^2-(2y-y'')^2}+y^2-yy''+\frac{1}{2}y'^2=c.
\end{align}

Comment: Can we make small angle approximations $\text{sin } a \approx a$?